# element.scrollTo / scrollIntoView don't scroll all the way sometimes on React app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've written a custom hook that takes a list of refs and scrolls to the element if there's a query telling it to. I have nav links that should scroll to their respective elements.

**It works as intended most of the time**, but **randomly** sometimes it just won't scroll accurately to that element, **won't scroll all the way**.

I am stuck.

```
function useScrollOnRedirect(elements: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>[]) {
    // ?scrollto=about
    const { search } = useLocation()

    useEffect(() => {
        const parsedSearch = new URLSearchParams(search)
        const query = parsedSearch.get("scrollTo")
        if (query) {
            const element = elements.find(el => el?.current?.id === query)?.current

            if (element) {
                element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
            }
        }
    }, [elements, search])
}
```

Tried element.scrollTo, element.scrollIntoView, window.scrollTo with refs and getElementbyid, useLayoutEffect....

Comment: Without a way to reproduce it, I'm afraid it will be difficult to help. One possible reason is buggy CSS that makes it scroll to the correct element but offscreen (if some elements overlap each other).

Comment: try using `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`, or otherwise wrap your functionality within a `requestLayoutFrame` call

Comment: sorry i meant `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: try a little setTimeout around 100ms, wrap scrollIntoView

Comment: Does adding `block: "start"` to the scroll option object more consistently scroll the elements into view? If not, then see the [notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#notes) regarding scrolling behavior.